# How to set global prototypes

Tags: node.js, electron

How i can set global prototypes like

```
String.prototype.test = function test() { /* Code */ };
```

Without include with `require`on each File?

Answer (score 1):

in your server.js file implement function one time then in other files just use it:

```
String.prototype.test = function test() { console.log('test')};
```

in foo.js of node project call this:

```
var str="bar";
 str.test();
```

Comment: Okay, i'm only want to implement it on the Main file?

Comment: sure, it has to execute one time for node engine